# JavaScript image slider not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slider

It just stays on a single image and doesn't advance the slide. I've checked other posts that have the same code and I can't find any differences. I need it all to be a single html as I'm using this for Wordpress.

Here is my html code:

```
<style>
#slideshow { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}
#slideshow > div {  
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
</style>

<div id="slideshow">
<div>
<a href="http://www.slideshare.net/billbayer/sell-or-die-the-sales-imperative">
<img src="http://www.billbayer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/sell.png" width="100%" height="100%">
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.slideshare.net/billbayer/bill-bayer-2013-economic-forecast">
<img src="http://www.billbayer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/economic.png" width="100%" height="100%">
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.slideshare.net/billbayer/lgr-fatal-illusions-april-2009">
<img src="http://www.billbayer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/fatal.png" width="100%" height="100%">
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.slideshare.net/billbayer/mastering-change-march-21-2013">
<img src="http://www.billbayer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/mastering.png" width="100%" height="100%">
</a>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rouse94/j6PSA/

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `javascript` code in your fiddle.

Your code works correctly.

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6PSA/1/)

Comment: Yes, my question is, how can I make it work inside of an html document? Do I need to change my script header?

Comment: well, what you want wont work in jsfiddle. It has separate sections for css,js and html. keep `style` and `script` tags inside `head` tag. and keep your js code within `document.ready` function. it will work. [Go through this.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/page-structure)

Comment: Well, my goal is to use this in a site so the html code above is just going to be copy/pasted into an html page, jsfiddle is just a means to show and test it. If I were to save the code above in an .htm file, the javascript doesn't work. I've also added the document.ready wrapper in the script section but still no luck.
Here's the page it's going to end up on: 

http://www.billbayer.net/bill-bayer-speaks/